# PHP&HTML: подстановка введённых значений в поля при неудачной отправке формы

Tags: php, html

Мне нужно, чтобы при неудачной попытке отправить форму введённые значения сохранились в полях. Я видел, что это делают так:

```
<form id="FeedbackForm" name="FeedbackForm" method="post" 
 action="request.php">

<input type="text" id="name" name="name" 
value="<?php echo $_POST["name"]; ?>"/>

<!-- продолжение формы -->
</form>
```

Т. е. мы подставляем в поля значения массива `$_POST`, если таковые имеются.

Но у меня почему-то не работает, т. е. не происходит подстановки в поля.
Скрипт `request.php` при запрете отправки всвязи с ошибками ввода возвращает на страницу с формой (его работа уже отлажена).

В чем может быть причина?

Comment: `var_dump($_POST);` что показывает на странице приема данных из формы?

Comment: Показывает `array (size=0)` при неудачной отправке... У меня скрипт отправляет почту и прерывается через `die()`, если хотя бы одно поле введено неправильно.

Comment: Что значит "неудачной отправке"? Если вы в форму данные ввели и отправили с браузера, то даже "неправильные" данные должны дойти до скрипта и попасть в `$_POST`.

Comment: Это значит, что скрипт обнаружил невалидные данные и завершил своё выполнение, не отправив email. Скрипт отправки данные `$_POST` действительно получает, по почему-то всё равно показывает `array (size=0)` при возврате на страницу с формой после прерывания скрипта.

Comment: Может, `die()` уничтожает массив `$_POST`?

Comment: Обычно так делают, когда форма и обработчик лежат в одном файле. У вас же пост запрос идет на файл `request.php`, а при возврате с `request.php`, массив `$_POST` обнуляется.

Comment: Ясно... а как тогда можно оставить поля заполненными? (JS использовать нельзя, т. к. это PHP-валидация для случая, JS отключен).

Comment: JS можно использовать с PHP в любом случае. Также можно обойтись HTML5 валидацией, но это не кроссбраузерно.

Comment: Можете также перенести обработчик из `request.php` в сам файл формы или же в файле формы инклудидь `request.php` по условию, если был отправлен пост. К слову, вариантов масса.

Comment: В смысле, в любом случае? Если у клиента выключен JS, то разве мы не теряем возможности его использовать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Т.к. у вас запрос (`action="request.php"`) идёт на другой файл, вижу несколько способов:

1. Яваскрипт (как я понял вам не подходит);
2. Производить обработку в том же файле, откуда отправляете форму;
3. Использовать куки (но их опять же, можно отключить);
4. Использовать сессии.

Comment: Ещё выше было сказано, что через include можно, да?

Comment: да, вы можете подключить файл где происходит обработка в файл, где находится данная форма :)

Comment: Отлично! Спасибо за идеальный ответ ~_^